# Hide log messages during startup on Ubuntu Gnome 15.10

Tags: boot

When Ubuntu is starting up, it shows some error log message on the screen.

[image: error messages]
[image: login tty message]

I want to hide all these messages, and see only the Ubuntu GNOME loading logo on the screen. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The boot loader is using a piece of software called *Plymouth*.

To work correctly you need to use [KMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mode_setting) compatible graphics drivers and sometimes just a bit of luck - in Ubuntu prior to 14.04 Plymouth hasn't really changed for 5+ years and is showing its age.  It is being updated in 14.04 and hopefully will work in a wider number of cases.

If you are using proprietary graphics drivers (often NVIDIA or AMD) then these are currently not KMS based and can be a cause of a very short/missing boot Plymouth picture.

One technique I use is to force Plymouth to run in a rather old but still useful technique called a [framebuffer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_framebuffer).

With this you'll get a longer display of the picture - you'll still get one TTY switch when moving from Plymouth to GDM.  This is not something you can workaround until the move to Wayland (assuming this promise is realised).

```
echo FRAMEBUFFER=y | sudo tee /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/splash
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but can show me step-by-step to fix this issue? (I using Ubuntu Gnome 15.10 on Lenovo Thinkpad T440)

Comment: @NgọcLương - start a terminal - copy and paste line by line those two lines.

Comment: great ! it's working now and hide almost all messages, just Error parsing PCC subspaces from PCCT and tty1 Login are still showing.

Comment: yep - covered that in the answer - thats the last TTY switch which you cannot workaround until Wayland (or Mir) is implemented.

Comment: how about the "error parsing.." message ? can I hide it ?

Comment: That depends upon what is producing the error ... If it is the kernel then no ... Nothing you can do.  If it is some other startup component you maybe able not running that service.  You will need to determine what service is causing the issue ....run dmesg in a terminal and look at whereabouts the.message is be produced.  This is really another question like"how can I determine what is producing this error and can I fix/disable the service on boot"